# Difference between `python3-ipython` and `ipython3` packages in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, apt, ubuntu-20.04

While querying on Ubuntu 20.04 for an ipython package (tried `pip3 install ipython` first, but that didn't give me the `ipython3` binary I was looking for) I found there are two packages:

```sh
$ ~/dev/romanyh$ sudo apt search ipython3
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
ipython3/focal,focal,now 7.13.0-1 all [installed]
  Enhanced interactive Python 3 shell

python3-ipython/focal,focal,now 7.13.0-1 all [installed]
  Enhanced interactive Python shell (Python 3 version)
```

I first tried `python3-ipython` because others (e.g., `pip` and `venv`) follow this naming convention, but it didn't give me the `ipython3` binary I was looking for. It seems the effect was similar to running `pip3 install ipython`.

I ended up installing both, the `ipython3` package did get me the binary I was looking for.

My question is: What is the difference between these packages? Why are both of them available?

Comment: some modules use C/C++ code which may need `.h` headers from other libraries and need C/C++ compiler - and this can makes problem to install it because you may have to install all needed elements before installing module with `pip`. And this is why some distributions create precompiled modules so it is easier to install them. For example module `wxPython` installed with `pip` has to compile all code from C/C++ code `wxWidgets` and it can take few hours. For the same reason there is [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: for the same reason there is [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) which gives Python with precompiled modules for Data science. [List of packages for py3.8 linux-64](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_linux-64/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same doubt today. Normally I get better result installing the distribution specific packages than using pip. (as already explained in the comments)

Edited: I though you should get the same results installing any of those packages... I was not able to execute ipython3 until I installed the package ipython. (this was in ubuntu cotainer on docker)

[python3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ipython3) (it is almost an "empty" package) that depends on [python3-ipython](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-ipython)